# voice call through Twilio using ios

Tags: php, ios, voice

I need to integrate voice call via wifi/3g in ios.
Now, I am using twilio for voice call for that I created test account for login.
but I don't have clear steps to follow how to integrate iOS SDK and php server files for backend.
please give me the sample code or

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest checking out the [Twilio Client for iOS quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client).  The quickstart will walk you through setting up both the client and server code needed to add Twilio Client to your iOS application, showing you how to both make an outbound phone call, and receive and incoming phone call in your application.

Hope that helps.